# Accessing JSON Key with Colon in Django Template

Tags: django, json, django-templates

I'm trying to access the `id` field in JSON in a Django template, but it has a colon in it.

When I include it in the template, I get the following error:

> "Could not parse the remainder: ':id' from 'result.id.attributes.im:id'".

I've tried escaping the name and the colon with no success.

I've included the JSON output when I use it's parent, as well as the Django template.

Any suggestions?

**HTML Output with JSON when passing up the parent (result.id.attribute) **

```
1 id: {**u'im:id': u'422689480'**, u'im:bundleId': u'com.google.Gmail'} Name: Gmail - Google, Inc.

2 id: {u'im:id': u'530755375', u'im:bundleId': u'com.kfactormedia.mycalendarfree'} Name: MyCalendar Free - K-Factor Media, LLC.

3 id: {u'im:id': u'518972315', u'im:bundleId': u'com.click2mobile.textGramFree'} Name: Textgram - Texting with Instagram FREE - click2mobile

4 id: {u'im:id': u'521863802', u'im:bundleId': u'com.appmosys.emoji2free'} Name: Emoji 2 Free - 300+ NEW Emoticons and Symbols - Appmosys
```

**Django Template**

```
<html>
<body>

{% for result in app_data.entry %}


<h3>

    {{ forloop.counter }}
    Id: {{ result.id.attributes }}
    Name: {{ result.title.label }}


{% endfor %}
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit to include the View:

**View**

```
def findAppRank(request,AppId=424909112):

URL="http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=300/genre=6007/json"

r=requests.get(URL)

output=r.content
data=json.loads(output)

AppData=data['feed']

t=get_template('myrank.html')

html=t.render(Context({'app_data': AppData, 'app_id': AppId }))

return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Could you please provide info of what you use and how you get the `app_data` ?

Comment: I added the view above. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I figured out a solution. If you pull up the entire array of values - you can select it by integer rather than name. "result.id.attributes.values.0"

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter.

```
{{ result.id.attributes|slice:"'im:id'" }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just changed that on the template and the results are coming back the same as above.